# iOS - NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore doesn't "actually" sync

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, synchronization, icloud

I am using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` to sync my application preferences and I am testing the sync process using two devices iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4.

As I change a preference in one device (say iPhone 3GS), it syncs the preference to `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` using the following code:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *keyStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [keyStore setObject:[userDefaults objectForKey:S_KEY_UI_SOUNDS]
                 forKey:S_KEY_UI_SOUNDS];

if ([keyStore synchronize]) {
    NSLog(@"TO ICLOUD - UI SOUNDS %@", [keyStore objectForKey:S_KEY_UI_SOUNDS]);
}
```

However two issues occurs:

**First:** although being registered for `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification`, I never receive it on iPhone 4. So if the iPhone 4 is active while the iPhone 3GS changes a preference, the iPhone 4 becomes unaware of it.

**Second:** As the iPhone starts to sync the preferences from `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, it never gets the new preference set using iPhone 3GS (see code below). This is despite of a successfully synchronization with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` (the synchronize method returns YES).

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *keyStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
if ([userDefaults synchronize]) {
    NSLog(@"FROM - UI SOUNDS %@", [keyStore objectForKey:S_KEY_UI_SOUNDS]);
}
```

Is there a fix for that? or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, Don't forget you should have your Apple ID account set on both devices for iCload...

Answer (score 4):

First `-synchronize` is not about "synchronizing with iCloud server". It's about synchronizing you changes and the local storage on disk. Once it's on disk, the underlying engine will push your changes to the cloud whenever it sees fit (generally after ~3s).

Second, you should subscribe to the store change notification.

In short, the first thing you should do when using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` is something like:

```
store = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
// subscribe immediately to any change that might happen to the store
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(storeDidChangeExternally:) name:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification object:store];

// get any changes since the last app launch right now (safer)
[store synchronize];
```

Lastly, synchronization with the cloud happens at "proper time" (you can't control it for now).

Just to give you an idea, once you have "synchronized" your in-memory changes to the disk, the engine will generally start a synchronization with the cloud "soon" and push your changes.

The server will then push a notification to the other devices which will then schedule a synchronization with the cloud as well.

Under normal circumstances, it takes ~7s for devices to be in sync.

Comment: For first, I will test that and consider a whole minute for synchronization. For second, I did that already and I don't receive anything in the called method (in your code, that's storeDidChangeExternally:). It could be due to same issue in first.

Comment: Check your iCloud account, check that Documents & Data switch is on and that you are over Wifi (or Cellular network **and** Documents & Data allows for sync over Cellular network)

Comment: Also, iOS 5 does not provide good ways for you to see when the iCloud sync actually happens. You should likely file a bug about that.

Comment: Yes, everything is fine and actually I am syncing documents with iCloud pretty well. It's really weird that the user will be able to sync documents but not the user preferences! I tried for whole 2 minutes with no sync occurred.

Comment: Can you look at the full Console (using Xcode organizer) and see if you see something related to `syncdefaultsd` there?

Comment: Yes, there are many lines. Here is one of them "Aug  4 08:08:32 unknown syncdefaultsd[1109] <Warning>: AOSKit ERROR: Invalid account info found for <MY ICLOUD ACCOUNT>, dsid='(null)', tokenFound=1. What does it mean?

Comment: ok, it seems that the authorization of your device with iCloud servers is stale. Go in iCloud settings, this should revalidate your account. If this does not solve the problem, delete and re-add the account on your device.